# how to force space to %20 in http_build_query?

Tags: php, json, http-headers

I am facing a problem, that the API endpoint expects one of parameters with `%20` replacing one of the spaces. Example:

```
$params = array(
           'client_id' => self::$client_id,
           'scope' => 'api%20offline_access', //here I need the %20 sign
           'response_type' => 'code',
           'redirect_uri' => self::$redirect_uri
          );
```

If I write `'scope' => 'api offline_access'` the space gets translated to `+` sign when passing it to `http_build_query()` function.

If I keep it like it is above, the sign is "wrapped" with more signs

I tried to find this answer in the function manual, but with no luck

Comment: Blind, blind, blind :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Paul replied :

```
http_build_query($params, null, null, PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

According to php doc for [enc_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#refsect1-function.http-build-query-parameters) parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Fix to upper comment

```
http_build_query($params, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
```

if 3-rd param (arg_separator) change null, the query string stick together.

```
file.php?query=firstpass=12345admin=root //no arg_separator

file.php?query=first&pass=12345&admin=root //arg_separator
```